python virtual environment on windows including user name in paths
I am using python virtual environments for a project stored in github that also receives contributions from other authors.  When I run they typical
python -m venv venv  to create it the resulting pyvenv.cfg file includes my username in the values
home = C:\Users\MYREDACTEDNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0   
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.12.5
executable = C:
\Users\MYREDACTEDNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe
command = C:\Users\MYREDACTEDNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m venv C:\Users\ChrisBode\OneDrive - kyndryl\SOaaP\documentation\gitpages\architecture.github.io\venv

Is there a best practice or method to create virtual environments in windows that are portable to other workstations operated by other users?

Users on other workstations should create their own virtual environments. You only need to provide a list of dependencies to be installed - for example, by using pip freeze to create a requirements.txt or conda list to create an export file.
